# display green junit test names in spring-tool-suite 4.11

Tags: eclipse, junit5, spring-tool-suite

In Spring Tool Suite 4.11 (Eclipse 4.20) is there some way you can get the names of tests that pass (Green) to be displayed, just as when they're failing? This is what it looks like now with all green tests:

[image: Green tests not displayed]

My reasoning is that while developing tests it would be useful to see the names also of those that pass.

Comment: Disable the button you have enabled (the one with the blue and red `x`) for that.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much @howlger! That's an answer so don't you want to post it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable** the ***Show Failures Only*** button (the only button that is enabled in your screenshot) **to display all**, failed and passed **tests**.

See [Eclipse help: *Java development user guide > Reference > Views > JUnit View*](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-view-junit.htm)

Comment: Marvellous. Thank you!